# Ensure unique items in List with Silverlight Databinding

Tags: silverlight, list, data-binding, architecture, class-design

in my Silverlight 4 application, I have a class `myClass` that contains a list of `element`s. This `element`s have a `name`-attribute that identifies them.

```
class element
{
  string Name { get; set; }
}

class myClass
{
  List<element> elements { get; }
}
```

To display the list of elements, I databind `myClass.elements` to a Silverlight-Listbox:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue=[None], Mode=TwoWay,
                       NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" />
...
```

This way, changes to the `Name` of the `element` is automatically propagated back. But: I need to make sure, that the `Name` is unique in `myClass.elements` (and some more constraints, depending on properties of `myClass`.

Naturally, the elements doesn't know who contains it (and it shouldn't know, I think). So my problem is: How can I check the contraints of the elements (in the setter of the Name-property)? I'd really like to use the Silverlight-Databinding, because it already implements Error Notification.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: One question, what do you expect the app to do if the user attempts to enter a duplicate? You could try having the element setter raise an event, that the container class subscribes to, to validate the item.

Comment: The App shall not save the value and the textbox shall display an error (via NotifyOnValidationError and ValidatesOnExceptions), so I guess the setter would need to raise the error. When I raise an event in the setter, I could not react in the setter to the validation result (not setting the property, raising the error) anymore, do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that `element` should implement INotifyProperyChange and `myClass` should be listening to changes, then checking for duplications, either throwing exceptions or indicating an error though IDataErrorInfo, INotifyDataErrorInfo or custom indicator. (so you implement Observer pattern, I assume, myClass here is an observer for its items).

For custom way, it's possible to set "IsDuplicate" property in duplicate items and bind it to background (red) color. That could be more useful for user, if s/he intentionally wants to set duplicate name here and then wants to fix some item entered before. Also if would be easier to find duplicates if you indicate all of them in the list.

**UPDATE:**

Here is indication of an error. Just changed item has border, duplicates for it - red font.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDuplicate}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
               Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Here is item template, note `ValidatesOnDataErrors`:

```
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is your Element class:

```
class Element : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value;
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    private bool _isDuplicate;
    public bool IsDuplicate
    {
        get { return _isDuplicate; }
        set
        {
            _isDuplicate = value;
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsDuplicate"));
        }
    }
    //IDataErrorInfo
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get 
        {
            if (IsDuplicate)
                return "Duplicate col" + columnName;
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

And finally, `myClass` should listen to PropertyChanged and invoke duplication check.

Comment: Hi Mikalai, thanks for the answer, this sounds like a good way! What I do not know yet is: When myClass indicates a (duplicating) error, how can I raise the (IDataErrorInfo) exception for the element, so that it's textbox displays it? Currently, I throw an Exception in the elements setter, but when myClass is checking for duplicates, I am not in the setter of the element anymore.

Comment: Ah, very good example, many thanks! The implementation of IDataErrorInfo is very helpful and might come in handy in other parts as well :)